# Is it possible to protect electronics on a cubesat from 100-1000g of acceleration

Tags: electromagnetism, magnets, propulsion, acceleration, rocketry

I am currently researching the feasibility of setting up a coilgun that launches Cubesats for a paper.

Comment: Any limit on cost, mass, complexity?

Comment: No restrictions on cost or complexity however the mass has to be reasonable. Since the paper is on Cubesats the full payload mass should be under 100kg.

Comment: Then how many Cubesats and what is the individual or total mass?

Comment: This question might be a better fit for SE Space Exploration

Comment: 1 cubesat per launch total payload mass <100kg

Comment: You can pot the electronics with various potting compounds to make the electronics effectively one solid mass, so no electronic components can move relative to the shell of the cubesat. How much weight can you afford to add with the addition of potting compound?